# Fullcalendar one feed with multiple JSON objects

Tags: java, json, multithreading, servlets, fullcalendar

Hello Fullcalendar followers, i am trying to make use of threads in my server side to load events to the calendar so i can get a better performance on loading events, meaning:

1 - I only have ONE evenSource feed:

```
eventSources: [othersources.funcmap] //Employee calendar MAP
```

2 - In the Servlet ( I'm working on java ):

```
I am gathering all JSON objets from different sources and joining them together in one large big object (with threads) that i want to send back to Fullcalendar.
```

2.1 - If i send them individual ( multiple ajax call meaning [othersources.vacations,othersources.faults etc...]) has Strings ( JSON FORMAT )  they work fine and all the feeds are loaded.

```
 This is the JSON object in the "individual" String -> `[{"title":"Vacation day","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc}]`
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is when i join them together i make the object like this:

```
[ 
   [{"title":"Vacation day","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc},{"title":"Vacation day","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc}],
   [{"title":"Fault day","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc},{"title":"Faul day","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc}],
   [{"title":"Birthday fault","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc},{"title":"Birthday fault","start":"02-09-2013", etc etc etc}]

 ]
```

This is actually a valid JSON object ( without the "etc etc etc" ofcourse :P ) but it doesnt work. fullcalendar wont render the events...

How can i join them together in one big object that Fullcalendar understand?
Or Fullcalendar only knows how to read simple JSON object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using an AJAX request to retrieve the events? Fullcalendar only will work with a simple JSON structure. I believe the best way to achieve that is treating the data before sending a response back.

Comment: Oooh ok then, i can't make a complex struture....thank you that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would probably be to flatten the events array before handing it to FullCalendar. But if you insist, then it is also possible by providing a function as a event source in FullCalendar.

The documentation for the function is here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

And this is the basic way to do it:

```
eventSources: [function (start, end, callback) {

    var eventArrays = [
        [{
            "title": "Vacation day",
            "start": new Date()
        }, {
            "title": "Vacation day",
            "start": new Date()
        }],
        [{
            "title": "Fault day",
            "start": new Date()
        }, {
            "title": "Faul day",
            "start": new Date()
        }],
        [{
            "title": "Birthday fault",
            "start": new Date()
        }, {
            "title": "Birthday fault",
            "start": new Date()
        }]
    ];

    // Using underscore.js to flatten the array
    var events = _.flatten(eventArrays);

    callback(events);
}]
```

You can check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvakulo/q5HET/1/

Comment: You mean flat like this [[{},{}],[{},{}]] ? Yes what i'm doing is like this, like a continuous String with the JSON format, i do not add any "\n", but it doesnt work. Nevertheless i'm going to explore this further and get back here when i achieve what i have in mind ;) thx for the answear.

Comment: Hi! By flat I mean an array like this [{},{},{},{}]. The first array should be without any subarrays - Regin

Comment: This is what i'm doing for each source, a flat one, and then i was trying to join them in one...i understand now this can´t be done my way, i will have to join them all without arrays ... thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this makes no sense at all. Multiple AJAX calls are faster, than trying to make one that returns all even with threads in the servlet.

But it worked with the Flat JSON i just joined them all together [{},{}...] with no subarrays.